# Freemember field helpers textarea

Tags: freemember

I Have a freemember form. I originally had a comments text area coded manually:

```
<textarea name="register_comments"></textarea>
```

But this meant that the field emptied if you submitted the form with a required field empty. To get round this I'm trying to generate the field using a field tag:

```
{field:register_comments}
```

But this outputs a text input rather than a text area. I've made sure that the field is set to 'Text Area' in the EE admin.

Is there any way round this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ben - you can format code (using markdown) by indenting 4 spaces (or select text and click the `{}` button in the text editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use something along the lines of

```
<textarea name="register_comments">
  {register_comments}
</textarea>
```

To get the previously entered contents of the field.